# Calling Perl script with PHP, passing variables and put result into a file

Tags: php, mysql, perl

I am near losing my mind cause of a perl script I want to call via PHP.

I have a PHP Form where I put in a MySQL Query which gets stored in a file and choosing some variables.

If I call any SHELL command like "top" ... everything works fine, but as soon as I try to call my perl script with variables, there are no results at all.

The file where the results should get stored stays empty.

That's the calling part from the PHP File:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = 'query.sql';
$query = $_POST['query'];
file_put_contents($file, $query);
$command = "perl /home/www/host/html/cgi/remote-board-exec.pl -sqlfileexec query.sql > /home/www/host/html/cgi/passthrutest.txt";
exec($command, &$ausgabe, $return_var);
```

There is no error message and i already tried debug things, but nothing helped :(

Comment: Try using exec "/usr/bin/perl /home/www/host/html/cgi/remote-board-exec.pl -sqlfileexec query.sql > /home/www/host/html/cgi/passthrutest.txt"

Comment: Are you assuming that `perl` is in the path when called via php?  Are you assuming that `query.sql` is in the current directory from the perspective of the command as well?  If all else fails, use absolute paths for everything.

Comment: Just tried it with absolute paths as well, result is the same ... nothing.
The paths of the files and scripts are fine, the script itself also works properly. But as soon as this -> "-sqlfileexec query.sql" is involved the result is empty

Comment: Can try eliminating the script entirely from the equation and just trying to get a call to perl to work.  `$command = "perl -e \"print qq{Hello World\\n}\"";`  If that doesn't work, then at least you've isolated your issues.  Then add a dummy script located in the directory as your other .pl that just prints Hello world.  Incremental changes like this will help you figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: That was the first thing i did, to see if the web server is allowed to run PERL scripts.
Nevertheless i found the Problem ... since i log in on the CLI with ssh key and the webserver doesn't have such a key it doesn't work. The PERL Script should fetch some data from different servers and PUTTY has the possibility for agent_forwarding.
Thanks to all your efforts and tries to help!
I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that perl is being executed? Perhaps you ought to replace the command with 'which perl' just to make sure, and to use the full path to Perl. Another idea is to make sure your:

- perl script is executable (use chmod)
- ensure it has '#!/usr/bin/perl' (or wherever your path to perl is)
- change the command to "/home/www/host/cgi/remote-board-exec.pl..." without the perl command
- dump the contents of your output array ($ausgabe) as if the command fails to execute you may find out what is happening.

Comment: Permissions are already set fine and the script itself is running perfectly. But as soon as there is the "-sqlfileexec query.sql" is being called, it brakes.
I already let the script tell me the $ausgabe and all i get is:

   $return_var ausgeben
0

$ausgabe ausgeben

Array
(
)

Comment: It may be the Perl script which breaks. Try putting the full path to the SQL script file in the command. Ensure your parameter only has a single `-` not `--`

Comment: Just tried absolute path for the script as well, also the output of the generated command is fine

Comment: Ok, it looks like there is something wrong with PHP.
I just copied the command which PHP should execute into the CLI and executed it manually ... there it works pretty fine and the results get stored in the text file I've mentioned.
Is there anything where i can check which permissions would be needed to make it running as it should?

Comment: i found the Problem ... since i log in on the CLI with ssh key and the webserver doesn't have such a key it doesn't work. The PERL Script should fetch some data from different servers and PUTTY has the possibility for agent_forwarding.
Thanks to all your efforts and tries to help!
I really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem - you ought to put an answer, explaining that it was an issue outside the problem as described. Such things happen quite often! :-)